# Week Dates on week number click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, calendar

Is there any way in asp.net or using javascript that when someone clicks on the week number shown on the calendar and I can get the dates (Monday to Friday) on a label?

Comment: seems you look for something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884175/jquery-datepicker-selecting-a-whole-week ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a server side solution in asp.net

Markup

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" />
<asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="Calendar1" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" />
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime input = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
    int delta = DayOfWeek.Sunday - input.DayOfWeek;
    DateTime firstDay = input.AddDays(delta);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
      Label1.Text += ((DateTime)(firstDay.Add(new TimeSpan(i, 0, 0, 0)))).ToShortDateString() + " -- ";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this jsFiddle example.

```
$(".calendar").datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        dateFormat: "'Week Number '" + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)),
        $(this).val('Week:' + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
    }
});​
```

Comment: can you give me the jsfiddle link?

Comment: Thanks but what I need is that when I click on the weeknumber, I want to get all the dates of that particular week.

Comment: Try this 
function getDateRangeOfWeek(week){
    var date = new Date();
    var currentWeek = $.datepicker.iso8601Week(date);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1 + (7 * (week -  currentWeek)));
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0;i < 7;i++){
     var d = new Date();
     d.setDate(date.getDate() + i)
     result[i] = d;
    }
    return result;
};

Comment: can you give me the fiddle?

Comment: Sorry I have not link for that But you can try with this code. I hope it is work